# How to implement volume pricing in WooCommerce / Dynamic Pricing

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the Dynamic Pricing plugin in WooCommerce, and it mostly works, but we'd like to be able to restrict quantities somewhat so that we can sell products in, for example, boxes of 100 in addition to individually.

Unfortunately, the Dynamic Pricing plugin doesn't quite give us what we need:

1. Ability to set discounts on individual items as usual with the Dynamic Pricing plugin
2. Ability to set discounts for boxes of 100 of the product (We could set a price rule with a min&max quantity of 100, but we would then need to set a rule for each multiple of 100. Not acceptable.)
3. Inventory management must function appropriately (using variations to set different prices based on quantity per box, for example, doesn't work).
4. User must be restricted to ordering in multiples of the boxed quantity, or the cart must automatically determine which combination of individual items vs boxes of items would be required to fulfil the quantity ordered.

Is there any code or plugin that would help us achieve this?

Comment: What about a [Product Bundle](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/) of 100 boxes?

Comment: Hmm, that has potential; I will try it.